# PostgreSql: Disable Numeric value out of range

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm creating an API with PHP and PostgreSQL.
This is one of the query I use:

```
SELECT id,  email,  first_name,  last_name, [...] FROM clients WHERE id = ?
```

The column "id" is an integer and I don't need a bigger type. ? is replaced by a value coming from the user.

But if the user sends a too big integer (9999999999999) PostgreSQL returns an error:

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR: value
>   \"99999999999999999999999\" is out of range for type integer

Should I check the overflow in the PHP logic ?

Can I turn this error into warning ?
The same query on MySQL doesn't fail...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The same query on MySQL doesn't fail" isn't a great recommendation (unless you're running MySQL in ANSI STRICT mode). MySQL accepts `0000-00-00` as a date, coerces invalid entries to nulls in places, etc, and often does so with at most a warning to tell you it's mangled your data.

That said, I do wish PostgreSQL offered versions of type conversion functions that returned an error code / returned null, so I could *explicitly* write:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(blah) VALUES (bigint_in_nullifinvalid('99999999999999999'));
```

It doesn't, though.

You can write such a function in PL/PgSQL but it's not efficient, and there's none built-in.

While I'm really happy that PostgreSQL won't mangle my data without being asked to, there are times I'd rather like it to mangle my data when I did ask it to.

In general it's better to:

- Validate on the application side first;
- Let the database enforce integrity; and
- Trap errors and report them to the user. You can match the `SQLSTATE` return to find out details about the error.

PostgreSQL doesn't have any "insert invalid data with warnings" option.

Comment: Ok, I'll add a if statement to check the overflow of "integer type". Thank you